# What is this wireless card's connector?

Tags: wireless-networking, connector, antenna

My laptop is currently having some wireless issues, so I decided to swap out my wireless cards. The problem is my laptop is a Ultrabook, it uses a non-standard antenna connector. Can some please help me identify the connector on this?

The wireless card can be found here, http://guide-images.ifixit.net/igi/diQ4deAFrSqvHFkU (source: IFIXIT).

This is only other information I could dig up on Google, http://www.wikidevi.com/wiki/Intel_Centrino_Advanced-N_6235 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those look identical to the standard antenna connectors - Apparently [Hirose U.FL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirose_U.FL) is the 'normal one', with the other major type being the [MMCX connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMCX_connector), which is similar but smaller. I'd guess its the latter

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the W. FL connector looks about the same size. I am not sure which one is correct.

Comment: It is a MHF4 connector.